# Need help trying to RANK with a GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, rank, dense-rank

I'm having trouble trying to rank each of our students, by the homegroup they are in.

Example fake data.

```
HomeGroup
1. Team RED
2. Team BLUE
3. Team Skeet
4. Team GREEN

Students
1. John, Score - 34, Team RED
2. Jill, Score - 87.3, Team RED
3. Fred, Score - 41, Team GREEN
4. Jane, Score 93, Team BLUE
...
```

etc.

My output is in the following

```
Scores
StudentId 1, Score 34, Rank - 5th 
StudentId 2, Score 87.3, Rank - 1st 
StudentId 3, Score 41, Rank - 9th 
StudentId 4, Score 94, Rank - 1st.
```

I'm trying to use DENSE_RANK .. and that works fine if i run this against a SINGLE HomeGroup (eg. homegroup = 1)... but i'm not sure how to do this over ALL the homegroups.

I'm guessing i need an Update query, which has a subquery ... and this subquery has it's own subquery ... ??

I'm pretty confused :( And i keep thinking about evil cursors which i refuse to use unless i've got a gun to my head (cause i believe it can be handled correctly with 'Set' notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the dense_rank of each student in the team:

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY Score DESC)
   FROM Students;
```

Is not clear to me what do you want the UPDATE though.

Comment: Perfect. PARTITION was the 'grouping' mechanism i needed. The update will be a simple UPDATE query with the select statement u suggestion, above. simple. wikid!